# CSS Zoom Issue In Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have been experimenting with CSS zoom property for quite a some time now. I took a large 1920X1200 size image and sliced it down horizontally into 10 pieces (10 each of 1920X120). I am positioning images on webpage like this -

```
<img src="images/img0_01.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;">
<img src="images/img0_02.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:120px; left:0px;">
.
.
.
<img src="images/img0_10.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:1080px; left:0px;">
```

And then I am applying zoom to to the entire document like this -

```
$("body").css("zoom","54%");
```

What I am expecting is to see all the 10 images as a single image, and I see as expected in Firefox/Chrome. However in Safari I see gaps between images (see attached screenshot). How can this be resolved ?

**Note** All the images have *margin*, *padding* and *border* set to 0. Positioning of the images should only be absolute with *top* and *left* values.

Would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks.

**[Live Demo](http://secansore.com/misc/CssZoomTests/)**

[image]

Comment: I believe this is due to rounding, and different browsers do it differently.  54% of 120 is 64.8 - not an even number, and relies on the browser to round.  And you are asking the browser to round the top position as well, not just the height.  Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16858031/870729

Comment: @cale_b thank you for your inputs, I can see now where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

One sort of quick hack I found that worked was just make the the images only 119 px apart instead of 120px. Looks much better on Safari and still looks pretty good on chrome.